# Which should I fix first?

Tags: audi, a4, camshaft-position-sensor

So I have two problems but money for only one of them. First I have to replace pcv valve hose or second Camshaft position sensor so which is more important and which one should i fix first? Car-Audi A4 B6 2.0Fsi

Comment: is the engine still working with a faulty Camshaft position sensor?

Comment: The car starts jerking and hesitating also its misfiring while idle. Car drives good while engine is cold but once it warms up it starts doimg all this stuff

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 4):

If you have to replace both and you can only replace one now, **replace the cam position sensor first**. If it goes completely out, the car will not run. It may not run as good without the new hose, but it will still run.

Something to think about, though, is that the hose really should not cost very much. Depending on which hose you need, it runs from (as of this post) $5-24 on [RockAuto.com](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/audi,2003,a4,1.8l+l4+turbocharged,1411232,exhaust+&+emission,pcv+(positive+crankcase+ventilation)+hose,11784). It should be fairly accessible and could most likely be replaced without issue by yourself, even if you don't have any mechanical abilities. The camshaft position sensor shouldn't be overly expensive either, but it is going to cost a lot more than the hose, that's for sure. I'm seeing it listed for ~$50 on RockAuto. These are usually a little bit harder to replace, but since there is only one connector and one bolt which holds it in place, is usually not hard to replace, either. If the shop does it, they'll triple the price of the sensor, and charge an hour's worth of labor, so looking at ~$250 to replace (total SWAG<sup>1</sup> on my part, but most likely the case).

<sub>Footnote:</sub>

<sup>1: Silly Wild Arse Guess</sup>